# AttributeError in terminal running Anaconda navigator (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, attributeerror, navigator

I am new to Anaconda and have recently posted a question about how Anaconda handles different Python versions (sorry for all the posts!). I think I have a handle on almost everything apart from the following error I have been encountering:

I am using a Dell computer with Ubuntu 18.04. I have a native Python 3.6 in my usr/bin and installing Microsoft VS (during the Anaconda installation) resulted in Python 2.7 also being installed there.
I have Anaconda with Python 3.7 and have created a few environments:

```
$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
# base                  *  /home/user-name/anaconda3
# myenv-3.6                /home/user-name/anaconda3/envs/myenv-3.6
# myenv-3.7                /home/user-name/anaconda3/envs/myenv-3.7
```

All seems to be working well apart from the fact that i noticed some weird errors when I launch the navigator from the command line: $anaconda-navigator.
At first I didn't realise anything because the GUI would open I would start using Spyder.

But I happened to look at my terminal window (left open after typing "$anaconda-navigator" and it has weird errors, which seem to be piling up over time. and seem to be the same error (although the "pipe" number changes).

```
QProcessPrivate::createPipe: Cannot create pipe 0x56312f2eea00: Too many open files
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user-name/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 495, in _conda_info_processed
processed_info = self._process_conda_info(info)
File "/home/user-name/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 606, in _process_conda_info
processed_info = info.copy()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I don't understand what this means, did I get some kind of error in my installation? Should I update conda maybe? Importantly:

- This error does NOT ALWAYS occur: sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. In my base environment, it doesn't seem to occur but it has occured twice in my "myenv-3.6" environment.
- It doesn't immediately occur. Sometimes I will be working for over an hour before it appears.

Any help would be deeply appreciated, I am desperate to get Anaconda working well.